# "Validation Failed" error in github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to create a repository on a github using curl command but it gives me the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Repository",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "name",
      "message": "name is too short (minimum is 1 characters)"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Repository",
      "code": "missing_field",
      "field": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I used is:

```
curl -u 'name' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repo","description":"This     project contains .... "}'
```

Comment: The format is not correct you need to provide repo-name as username\reponame have a look here.. https://coderwall.com/p/mnwcog

Comment: I tried it but did not work as well

Comment: Are you authenticated already?

Comment: Is another pull request already open?